# Email Notfication based on the field value

Tags: apex, workflow, scheduled-apex

HI I have the following field value.

1. type (pick-list) values [daily, weekly]
2. Count (number).
3. end date
   If I choose daily and 2 in the above field. two mail should send to the owner. till the endate field.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a 4th field: "Next Email" (Date Time). There you can store a date at which you want to send the next email.

**Solution 1**

1. Create a workflow (time-based). Add a workflow action to send the email.
2. Create a scheduled batch job. (And run your scheduled batch job every 15 min). Query all records `WHERE NextEmail__c < Now`. For each of these records, you can set a new "Next Email Date" based on your 3 fields above.

**Solution 2**

Create a trigger within the trigger you can update the next Email field based on your criteria. In a second step, you schedule a job (through your trigger).

The scheduled job updates the Next Email Field based on your criteria and send a new mail.

Comment: How to create Create a workflow (time-based). ?

Comment: e.g. http://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/salesforce-crm-the/9781782170761/part28.html?autoStart=True

Comment: Really Thanks. Can you answer for this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/joint-report-with-bucket-field ?

Comment: @Lemon if this answered your question, at least mark it as an answer before asking him to answer a new one. :|

Comment: Christian Deckert please answer the above...